# Hyde accessing the original Jekyll's memories

Tags: plot-explanation, jekyll

In [Jekyll (TV series)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_%28TV_series%29), Hyde starts to remember memories of Tom. He even ends up recollecting memories of the original Jekyll. Since Hyde shares his mind with Tom, should the memories that he can access be restricted to only Tom's?

In case we go with the Genetic Memory theory, where the memories of your predecessors is passed down genetically, would this mean that Hyde should be able to access memories of his mother too? Ms. Utterson (Sophia) is the mother and Hyde should be able to see in to her memories as well. Once Hyde and Tom establish their mind-meld, the memories are shared. Why does it still remain a shocking surprise to Tom when Ms. Utterson confronts him as his mother? Shouldn't he have expected / known this?

Comment: In the show they do mention that Hyde's ability to remember is due to genetic memory, but this only seems limited to Hyde, Tom, and the original Jekyll/Hyde.  This may be due to Tom/Hyde being a perfect genetic throwback, which his mother isn't.

How this all works isn't explained well though.