# What did they need Hyde for?

Tags: plot-explanation, jekyll

I just watched the finale of Jekyll (2007), and while I found it both shocking and genius, I'm not quite sure I understand the plot of the show in the light of the final revelation.

If I understand it correctly, Utterson is a descendant of the original Jekyll/Hyde, and Jackman is the son of Utterson. Both inherited the „curse“ apparently, but for some reason Jackman needs a Claire-Clone to trigger it.

Why does Utterson need Hyde for her company, when she herself is a „Hyde“?  (as indicated in the very last scene) Is there something different about Jackman's alter ego?

Can someone explain the overall plot arc of the show, Utterson's motivation and how the inheritance/triggering of the curse works?

Comment: Ah, a fellow Jekyll fan! I too had this question and also another one : http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28207/hyde-accessing-the-original-jekylls-memories

Answer (score 1):

Because they want a clone or the original Hyde.  While Utterson is a descendant of Hyde, she's regarded as an imperfect version.

By contrast, Jackman is perfect natural genetic duplicate,

> a perfect throwback, a chance in a million

By playing all the psychological tricks on Jackman, they hoped to bring forth Hyde as the perfect specimen, and clone/dissect him to discover why he is the way he is.

Hyde has superior strength and intellect.  He can manipulate things remotely (apparently with some form of telepathy).  He can heal wounds very quickly.

If Utterson and co. can determine how it all works, they could copy it, creating a medical empire.  At least, that's the gist I got.  They might also have military contracts.  TBH, their motives are never entirely clear.